# Impact of disabling site setting "Allow Access to Standard Salesforce Pages"

Tags: community, customer-community, site.com

Recently an issue was brought to our attention where a link was made available in our Lightning community to a Knowledge article but it was linked to the standard Salesforce page. That page of course is no remotely similar to configured community article page.

I found the site setting above, which makes sense in how it functions. When enabled if you had not specifically provided a default page for a given object, then the community will use the standard one. Disabling it in a sandbox resolved the odd behavior however my question is this.

Why, if you have already a fully lightning branded community, would you ever want to send a customer to  a standard page? I'd think there wouldn't be many use cases for this, much less setting it to default, as Salesforce has done.

Lastly of course would be wondering if there is any unexpected negative impact if we disabled this.
[image]